# How do I create a dependent dropdown?

Tags: forms, 6, ajax

I need to create a dependent drop down like, with values that are loaded with AJAX depending from the value selected in another dropdown.

What could should I use in Drupal 6 that is equivalent to the following one?

```
 $form['sandbox_ajax_dropdown']['province'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Province'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => _load_province(),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event'=>'change',
      'callback' =>'sandbox_ajax_dropdown_city',
      'wrapper' => 'city-wrapper',
    ),
  );
```

Comment: You can use [`AHAH`](https://www.drupal.org/node/331941) for that

Comment: Thank you @Clive. As per your suggestion, i have used ahah_helper to achieve the ajax code  $form['tag_switching']['channel'] = array( '#type' => 'select', '#title' => t('Channel'), '#options' => array( 'city-hall' => t('City hall'), 'albany' => t('Albany'), 'media' => t('Media'), ), '#default_value' => $channel_default_value, '#ahah' => array( 'event' => 'change', 'path' => ahah_helper_path(array('tag_switching')), 'wrapper' => 'tag-switching-wrapper', ), );